# JQuery remove animiation from .show() and do something once element is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show an element with jquery, and then submit a form once the element has been shown. I have the following code.

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
        var self = this;
        e.preventDefault(); 

        $('#element').show({
            complete: function() {
                self.submit();
            },
        });
});
```

The problem I have is that the above code adds an animation when showing the element. I want  the element to show straight away rather than ease in (i.e. no animation). I have tried setting a duration option to `duration:1`, but this seems to have undesired behaviour and doesn't show the element at all. I've also tried setting the `easing` option to `null`, but no joy either.

I've also tried the code below (as this has no animation with it):

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
        var self = this;
        e.preventDefault(); 

        $('#element').show();
        self.submit();
});
```

But the problem here is that the element isn't shown before the form is submitted.

Any ideas how I can show the element with no animation, and once the element is onscreen, sumbit the form?

Using JQuery 1.9.1

UPDATE:

After several hours of hair pulling, the issue I was having seems to be down to Safari 6.0.3 . It seems that Safari does not wait for the element to show before running the next line of script - all other browsers do. Setting even just a small time delay seems to fix this issue.

Comment: If you immediately submit the form (and leave the page), in which time would you expect to see the shown element?

Comment: I'd expect it to be shown immediately with no animation

Comment: But there's no time to be seen on the screen if the page is immediately left! How do you confirm that is was not shown?

Comment: well the page doesn't go blank when the form is submitted...

Comment: Yes, but it is not updated any more. You will need to put the submit in a small timeout to get the DOM updated and the screen redrawn *before* submitting.

Comment: yes, i know that, thats why I am using completed: to submit the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
        var self = this;
        e.preventDefault(); 

        $('#element').show();

        // Delay the form submission

        setTimeout(function()
        {
             self.submit();
        }, 1000);
});
```

It's the same as your example, but I've added the code to delay the execution of form submit (self.submit()) one second after the initial action (1000 milliseconds).

Comment: hmm quite hacky. I'd rather use an on completion callback if one exists

Comment: Although fundamentally I don't like this solution, it is the only one that works. There seems to be some issue in Safari 6.0.3 that does not wait for the element to show before running the other lines of code. This solution fixes it.

Comment: Great, also if you don't want to wait the whole second, you can play with the second setTimeout() argument — now it's 1 second (e.g. try setting it to 1 instead of 1000 — that will mean almost no waiting).

Comment: I believe that the issue with other solutions is probably because the browser only refreshes the view after the whole block of code in the callback has finished it's execution (and setTimeout() moves the submit() call out of this callback thus allowing the refresh to take place before submit())

Answer (score 0):

The default duration for show is `400`.

I see that you have tried setting duration to 1.But,I am not sure how you did that.

Try this :

```
$('#element').show( 0, function() {
                self.submit();
            }
```

Some example I just did on these lines (No form submitting,but simple stuff)

You can find it [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/A3etg/)

There

```
   $("#sample").hide();
    $("#new").hide();
    $('#clickme').click(function() {
      $('#sample').show(0, function() {
        // Animation complete.
          $("#new").show("slow") // Instead of this you submit your form
      });
});
```

Comment: Nope still not working for me. I click, the alert is show, i click the alert away, THEN the element is shown (in a position that was NOT covered by the alert previously).

Comment: oh really in fiddle ??? with duration zero ? Well here is the thing, as in [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/A3etg/2/) , the statements in that function will only be executed after the animation completes (No doubt about it) . Now,you don't want the animation,so it is literally both happening at the same time !! If you don't want that to happen,then as suggested by some solutions above you got to use some time delay .I guess that is the only solution and btw animation looks cool,wonder why you dun want it! ;)

Comment: Yes, in that fiddle link. I have just done a browser test and it appears that this only happens in Safari 6.0.3 (which is new I believe). At least I've worked out the problem now. Been driving me crazy! BTW, maybe delete some of your comments to tidy things up a bit :-)

Answer (score 0):

Could also:

```
$('#element').css({display: ''})
self.submit();
```

Since 'show' works on the `display` property.

Following your feedback; my next attempt would be along the lines of...

```
$("form").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#element").css({display:''});
  submitForm($(this));
});

function submitForm(form) {
  form.is(":visible")? form.submit()
  :  setTimeout(function() {
       submitForm(form);
     }, 50);
}
```

Hopefully that works but no guarantees as im on mobile

Comment: This is the same as my second code example. The element isn't shown before form is submitted

Answer (score -1):

### Use $.Deffered

Here's a deferred example that will truly "wait" until `#element` is shown to submit the form, regardless of the type of animation or duration:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AaronBlenkush/xHZ5F/)

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    var self = this;
    $('#element')
        .show(duration)         //Use a duration of 0 to remove animation
        .promise()              //Get deferred object
        .done(function(){       //Set the "success" callback for the deferred
            self.submit();      //Submit the form
        });
    return false; //Prevent immediate submission
});
```

Comment: This is very strange. Your fiddle example works for me, but when I set duration to 0 the element is shown immediately in fiddle example, but not shown at all when I add to my site.

Comment: @Gaz_Edge I'm curious are you using any jQuery plugins? (If you saw the previous comment - I see now that you're using jQuery 1.9.1)

Comment: 1.9.1 - no plugins, no other script. I experienced the same in my code above when setting option duration:0. In fact any duration less than about 50 i get no element shown

Comment: @Gaz_Edge It *sounds* like the element is not being selected... Can you confirm that `$('#element')` is returning the correct DOM element? I usually just do `console.dir($('#element'));` -- but do you mean it *does* show if you do a duration > 50?

Comment: it does show for durations > about 50 (not extensively tested) but defo does not show for duration 0 or 1. Using following for JQuery /ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: @Gaz_Edge Hard to say, but I would post full code to a jsFiddle if possible. If it's a lot of code, it would be good to trim it down as much as possible (while retaining the issue). Maybe add an "UPDATE" section to your question describing this problem.

Comment: have just tried my full code in fiddle and it works! No idea why its not working on my simple test page...